# category url format in nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net, nopcommerce

I would like to know how I can make the url's for the categories static. For example http://localhost:3547/category/53-cellphones.aspx is what I have currently but yesterday it was http://localhost:3547/category/1-cellphones.aspx.
I want to know how can I make the number in the category name static, e.g. 1-cellphones.aspx to be like that all the time, I don't want to be changed tomorrow to 3-cellphones.aspx for example.
Is that possible?
Thanks

Comment: This is normally the id of the category in the database.  Can you check Nop_Category and see what rows are there.

Comment: yes that's true, thanks. Maybe you can post it as an answer so I can select your answer for correct. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normally the id of the category in the database.

Can you check the **Nop_Category** table and check you don't have duplicate rows.